# how to concatenate two lines (one indented) in a txt in linux?

Tags: linux, txt

I have a txt file like this:

```
chr1    1300000 1350000
    chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    0
chr1    1500000 1550000
    chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    -150583
chr1    1950000 2000000
    chr1    1785285 1891117 -   105833  GNB1    -58884
```

And I would like to concatenate each two lines (like this)

```
chr1    1300000 1350000 chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    0
chr1    1500000 1550000 chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    -150583
chr1    1950000 2000000 chr1    1785285 1891117 -   105833  GNB1    -58884
```

I've been googled and I tried `paste -s -d '\n' file` but doesn't work as desired
Any advice?
Thank!

Comment: try `sed N file`?

Comment: It concatenated with no space the cols 2-5

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to play around with...

```
#cat test.txt
chr1    1300000 1350000
    chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    0
chr1    1500000 1550000
    chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    -150583
chr1    1950000 2000000
    chr1    1785285 1891117 -   105833  GNB1    -58884
#printf "%s\n" "$(cat test.txt|grep -o -E 'chr1.*[0-9]{7}.*[-].*[A-Z].*')" >test.res
#cat test.res
chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    0
chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    -150583
chr1    1785285 1891117 -   105833  GNB1    -58884
```

Answer (score 0):

From terminal you can just do something like this:

```
$ echo -n "chr1    1300000 1350000 " >> file.txt 
$ echo -n "chr1    1335278 1349418 -   14141   DVL1    0" >> file.txt
```

The -n prevents the echo function from adding a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 'N;s/\n//' file
```

But you could just:

```
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2; do
    echo "$line1 $line2"
done <file
```

Comment: it doesn't work at all, the output is like this                                                                       `chr1 chr1000 1020120 1056116 + 35997 AGRN -443885chr1 1500000 1550000
chr1 chr1000 3652516 3736201 + 83686 TP73 003647chr1 3600000 3700000`

Comment: tested on https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/PersonalKookyDeprecatedsoftware#main.sh . I gues your file has dos line endings, make sure they are not there.

Comment: yes it seems that there is an ending in two parts `chr1 3600000 3700000
|chr1 3652516 3736201 + 83686 TP73|0 ` just before second "chr" and after gene name. Suggestions?